# In Vue.js, how do I enable buttons in a v-for loop when an input is changed?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Here in my baseline code:

https://plnkr.co/LdbVJCuy3oojfyOa2MS7

I would like the 'Press' me button to be enabled for any given row whenever the input field changes.

I've modified the code by adding:

```
:disabled="isButtonDisabled(dino)
```

to the button

and then creating the following stub function:

```
isButtonDisabled: function(dino) {
}
```

After this, I'm getting stuck. How can I compare the current value to the initial value to determine whether or not I should enable the button?

Edit: In case I'm being unclear, the bottom line is that I want a button to be enabled whenever the corresponding input has been changed.

Comment: not really sure what you are asking from the description

Comment: Hi Keith, I've edited my question to hopefully add some clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the `@input` or `@change` event on the input to enable the button.

```
<input type="text" v-bind:value="dino" @input="enableButton" />
```

Then down in your methods handle the event. You could also pass `dino` as a parameter to the `@input` event handler.

```
enableButton: function(e) {
  // determine input from e and toggle button
}
```

Comment: This indeed is a simpler and better solution :)