# In Vue.js, how do I enable buttons in a v-for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Currently, I have:

https://plnkr.co/edit/LdbVJCuy3oojfyOa2MS7

[image]

I would like the "Press me" buttons enabled when the input changes.

So far, I have code that detects when the input has changed:

```
enableButton:function(dino) {
  console.log("input changed", dino);
}
```

but in the `enableButton` function, it's unclear what code I need to enable the corresponding button.

How do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Vue.js, how do I enable buttons in a v-for loop when an input is changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52755359/in-vue-js-how-do-i-enable-buttons-in-a-v-for-loop-when-an-input-is-changed)

Answer (score 0):

I modifed your Page so that the `:disabled` simply checks if the current Input is different from the Value that was there before, but this solution does not change the original Dino value, if you want that then comment then I modify my solution further.

https://plnkr.co/edit/lyEXI8qgeLBykgIVlS29?p=preview

Comment: Hi Badgy, thanks for your help. If you could also show the solution where the original Dino value is updated, that would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could track the disabled state of all dinos in a new property:

```
data() {
  disabled: {
    Triceratops: true,
    Velociraptor: true,
    Tyrannosaurus: true,
  },
}
```

Then, bind the button's `disabled` to that property:

```
<button :disabled="disabled[dino]">Press me</button>
```

In `enableButton(dino)`, clear the `disabled` state of the given `dino`:

```
enableButton(dino) {
  this.disabled[dino] = false;
}
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    dinos: [
      "Triceratops", "Velociraptor", "Tyrannosaurus"
    ],
    disabled: {
      Triceratops: true,
      Velociraptor: true,
      Tyrannosaurus: true,
    },
  }),
  methods: {
    enableButton(dino) {
      this.disabled[dino] = false;
    },
    onClick(dino) {
      alert(dino)
    }
  }
});
```

```css
button:disabled {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17"></script>

<div id="app">
  <template v-for="dino in dinos">
    <div>
      <input type="text" :value="dino" @input="enableButton(dino)">
      <button @click="onClick(dino)" :disabled="disabled[dino]">Press me</button>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```